# The Footer is not displaying in html5 Page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html5-canvas

I am attaching my index page and CSS pages. I am unable to see complete content of my footer (on actual 100% zoom). The scroll bar is also not visible on right. Every time I have either zoom in or zoom out. Please help.

Here is the code http://5focusm.com/mywebsite.zip

Comment: you should create a jsfiddle or some code dont think anyone is going to download a zip from a new account

Comment: Please help me now! https://jsfiddle.net/ggvt44fg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have `overflow:hidden;` on your body tag from what I can see.

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

remove that or change it to `auto`